# Two Models vs One Model for Person Detection and Object Detection

Tags: object-detection

Is it possible to do person detection and object detection within one model? The training data would be images annotated with bounding boxes for objects and people.  Because normally object detection and person detection are done separately? Is there any research about models that simultaneously detect both people and objects?

Comment: By person detection you mean outputting a bounding box for people or face recognition? Thanks @PrimeNumber

Comment: @ClementHui: bounding box for people.

Comment: object detection also can detect persons. People can be a class of object to classify.

Comment: Hi @PrimeNumber I have added an answer, hope that it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can classify people bounding box with object detection. State of the art object detection model have people as one of the class in the object detection, as shown here:
[image]

As you can see the image have both object bounding box and people bounding box.